# Duplicate messages which I got from service?

Tags: javascript

I am using BehivourSubject for recieve data, also using websocket but websocket is not important for now. For now is very important why I always got duplicated message from BehivourSubject.

First check my service:

```
hubMessage$ = new BehaviorSubj 
}
```

I listening web socket and new location.
When I got new location I send to my component:

```
  private test = () =>  
    }
```

What is problem?

When I check my console.log(' message, d$).

First message:

```
hub message  + data
```

Second message:

```
hub message  + data
hub message  + data
```

Third message:

```
hub message  + data
hub message  + data
hub message  + data
hub message  + data
```

....

and every next time I get twice as many messages as the previous ones.

**Question, do I duplicate messages on the frontend or do I get it from the backend? Just one, after a few minutes my system crashes because I have too many messages.**

Comment: Why do you want to call ` this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved()` on your subscription?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the method this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved() every time when you are receiving data from the same service which you have subscribed earlier.

Service emits the location through websocket. On subscribing to that location, you again call the method which again initializes one another instance of web socket. This is creating a never ending loop which at the end results into system crashing because of memory is all used up.

```
    private newCoordinate = () => { 
      this.signalRService.hubMessage$.subscribe(
        (data: any) => { 
           // Remove the below line
          // this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved()
          this.locationCoords = data;
          if (this.locationCoords.location) {
            this.latitude = this.locationCoords?.location?.latitude
            this.longitude = this.locationCoords?.location?.longitude
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

Comment: I am try it but no work. I got message in console warning no error -> 2021-05-05T08:31:55.887Z] Warning: No client method with the name 'NewLocation' found. When I check my network WS part I got new message and it work... I have problem in frontend